# how do i use do-while loop to prompt for and read the strings from the user? Array Lists

Tags: java, arraylist, do-while

I keep getting an error with my code specifically at

```
ArrayList<String> input[i]= (i + 1) + " " + ArrayList<String> input[i];
```

the error tells me "; expected" what am I doing wrong here?

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("how many lines of text do you want to enter");

        int numLines = 0;
        numLines = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
        scnr.nextLine();

        int i = 0;
        do{

            System.out.println("Enter your text: ");
            String text = scnr.nextLine();
          ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
            i++;


        for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
        {
           ArrayList<String> input[i]= (i + 1) + " " + ArrayList<String> input[i];
        }

        for (String element: ArrayList<String> Lines)
        {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
            } while(i != 0);
```

Comment: what line does it say the error is in?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the semicolon. Your assignment on this line is incorrect.            ArrayList<String> input[i]= (i + 1) + " " + ArrayList<String> input[i];    You need to take out the type declaration to the part on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

As you have

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
```

within your loop, it means that it will get re-declared and initialised for every iteration of that loop, so move this declaration to before your `do`

Next, to add to this loop, use `add` method

```
String text = scnr.nextLine();
input.add (text);
```

To simplify, you do not need a `do` as you have a number of times that you want to loop

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.println("how many lines of text do you want to enter");

    int numLines = scnr.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    scnr.nextLine();

    ArrayList <String> lines = new ArrayList <> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter word...");
        String text = scnr.nextLine();
        lines.add(text);
    }
```

To print your list, you can then do

```
for (int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println (lines.get(x));
}
```

**output**

```
how many lines of text do you want to enter
5

Enter word...
one
Enter word...
two
Enter word...
three
Enter word...
four
Enter word...
five
one
two
three
four
five
```